# React setState returning empty result from server, when the result gets received successfully

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, mern

I have the code as follows:

```
const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1);
useEffect(() => {
    const readDashboardPosts = async () => {
        let limit = 4;
        try {
            const res = await axios.post( );
            setFriendPosts(res.data.posts);
            console.log('pos', res.data.posts);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err)
        }
    }
    readDashboardPosts();
    console.log('friend-posts from state: ', friendPosts);
}, [])
```

On first render, my console.log are as follows:

```
pos (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
friend-posts from state:  []
```

So, I did get the results from server successfully, since console.log of 'pos' is working but after I set state, it's not working properly as I get empty array although I am using async await. I also tried this with useCallback, but no luck.

Comment: setter function for a state is async. If you want to log the state change, do this `useEffect(()=>{if(friendPosts.length>0)console.log(friendPosts)},[friendPosts])`

Comment: The dependency of friendPosts turns it to an infinite loop

Comment: Have you created another useEffect or just added the code in the one you already have?

Comment: The useEffect I added above, should be a new one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all , setState is asynchronous

second , to see if the state is set successfully either use React Devtools
Go to Components and inspect your component

Or try using useeffect like this :

```
useEffect(()=>{
    console.log('friend-posts from state: ', friendPosts);


} ,[friendPosts])
```